# How can i get the start and end time of clicked appointment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-scheduler

Hi I am very new to Scheduler control can anyone tell me how do i get start and end time  and also date  when i select the  the time say 4 pm in the code behind and then wheni save and when i try to retrieve it i am getting different time  this is how i am doing can any one tell me what is the problem

```
protected void RadScheduler1_AppointmentInsert(object sender, SchedulerCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Appointments.Add(new AppointmentInfo(e.Appointment));
            DateTime start = e.Appointment.Start;
            DateTime end = e.Appointment.Start.AddMinutes(((RadScheduler)sender).MinutesPerRow);
            string startdate = e.Appointment.Start.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **TimeZoneOffset** property from the RadScheduler. 
Let me know if any concern.